# Android: redrawable ListView with Adapter inside TabActivity. View doesn't change FIXED

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost, tabactivity

So I have a ListView inside my TabHost and I want to redrow its content every time I change the tab. Nevertheless I never get the list drawed.

My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
            <!-- Dishes Panel  -->
            <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:id="@+id/dishSelector"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        tools:context=".MenuSelectorActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And my TabActivity:

```
 public class MenuSelectorActivity extends TabActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory{    
        private ListView dishSelector;
        private DishSelectorAdapter dishSelectorAdapter;
        private TabHost tabHost;
        private DishDao dishDao;
        private DishTypeDao dishTypeDao;
        private Map<Integer, List<DishPojo>> dishesByType;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_selector);

            tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
            tabHost.setup();
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            dishDao = new DishDao(this);
            dishTypeDao = new DishTypeDao(this);

            dishesByType = new HashMap<Integer, List<DishPojo>>();//new ArrayList<List<DishPojo>>();

            List<DishType> types = dishTypeDao.list();
            TextView dTypeNameView;

            for(DishType dType : types){
                dishesByType.put(dType.getId().hashCode(), createDishPojoList(dishDao.list(
                        new String[]{DishDbContract.SQL_WHERE_CLAUSE_LIST_BY_TYPE}, new String[]{dType.getId()})));
            }
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

            for(DishType dType : types){
                dTypeNameView = new TextView(this);
                dTypeNameView.setText(dType.getDescription());
                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(dType.getId()).setIndicator(dTypeNameView).setContent(this);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            dishSelector = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dishSelector);
            if(dishSelectorAdapter == null){
                dishSelectorAdapter = new DishSelectorAdapter(this, dishesByType.get(tag.hashCode()));
            }else{
                dishSelectorAdapter.setDishToSelect(dishesByType.get(tag.hashCode()));
            }
            dishSelector.setAdapter(dishSelectorAdapter);
            dishSelector.refreshDrawableState();
            return dishSelector;
        }
        private List<DishPojo> createDishPojoList(List<Dish> dishes){
            //creates a list of Pojos
        }
}
```

The adpter DishSelectorAdapter has been already used in other situation and it works ok, so I don't think it is relevant here.

Thanks by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well, it was not as hard as I've thought. The answer was just in front of my eyes.

I didn't put the ListView inside de FrameLayout. The correct code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
            <!-- Dishes Panel  -->
            <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:id="@+id/dishSelector"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        tools:context=".MenuSelectorActivity" />
       </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Still rest of the code has some issues to work about, but nothing I coudln't fix with a quick look.